# flutter - how do calculate average the data in list?

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I have a `List<Comment>` about food from users.
It looks like this:

```
[
    {userId: 1,
     rating: 4.5
    },
    {userId: 2,
     rating: 4.0
    },
    {userId: 3,
     rating: 3.5
    },
    {userId: 4,
     rating: 3.0
    }

   ...
];
```

I want to get the average rating. `AVERAGE = Number of ratings : total user`, how do I apply this in dart?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
  var values = [
    {'userId': 1, 'rating': 4.5},
    {'userId': 2, 'rating': 4.0},
    {'userId': 3, 'rating': 3.5},
    {'userId': 4, 'rating': 3.0}
  ];

  var result = values.map((m) => m['rating']).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / values.length;
  print(result);
```

Comment: No one can beat you in questions related to json.

Comment: Hi @Günter Zöchbauer, what if I want to sort the list from the highest rating - the lowest?

Comment: only on the phone. There should be a question about how to sort a map by value where this is explained

Comment: This answer is outdated. See a better solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660580/8539278

Answer (score 30):

**In 2021** dart has the built-in `average` method from the `collection` package which can be used on an `Iterable`.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
 var values = [
    {'userId': 1, 'rating': 4.5},
    {'userId': 2, 'rating': 4.0},
    {'userId': 3, 'rating': 3.5},
    {'userId': 4, 'rating': 3.0}
  ];

  var result = values.map((m) => m['rating']!).average; 

  print(result); // prints 3.75
}
```

You might also be interested in the `.sum` method from the same package.

Answer (score 2):

I did this by adding the values with the fold function and then dividing by the total. Here is an example:

```
var values = [
    {'userId': 1, 'rating': 4.5},
    {'userId': 2, 'rating': 4.0},
    {'userId': 3, 'rating': 3.5},
    {'userId': 4, 'rating': 3.0}
];

List<double> ratings = values.map((e) => e.price!).toList();
double sum = ratings.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c);
if (sum > 0) {
   double average = sum / ratings.length;
}
```